# Generate 1 random number between -1 and 1 in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and I need to add one random number between -1 and 1 to the equation. I also need to generate a random number between -5 and 5.

I need float number not int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a random double between -1 and 1:

```
a = 2*rand(1)-1;
```

And between -5 and 5:

```
b = 5*(2*rand(1)-1);
```

Best,